# cached network image package error after update 3.0?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-upgrade

After upgrading to the Flutter 3.0, I got error in package `cached_network_image`.

```
/D:/flutter_sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:468:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/D:/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
```

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to pubspec for now:

```
dependency_overrides:
  cached_network_image:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/XuannThucc/flutter_cached_network_image.git
      path: cached_network_image
      ref: ff72f00f142f13d889d7549e013af91cb0b523ab
```

github issues: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/732

**(this is temporary solution author's will soon patch this)**